# Sum of log distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

Suppose $x_i\sim N(0,1)_\mathbb{C}$ is a i.i.d. random variable from a complex distribution and

$$P=2^n|x_1| |x_2|...|x_n|$$

Rewriting $x_i=r_ie^{i\theta}$; that is,

$$P=2^n r_1 r_2...r_n,~r\geq 0.$$

Now define $L:= Ln(P)$,

**$$L=nLn(2)+Ln(r_1)+Ln(r_2)...Ln(r_n).$$**

(i) **Question**:**I'd like to know if there is a pdf for $L$**.

For $r_i$ there is the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution), which arises in the case of random complex numbers whose real and imaginary components are i.i.d.with equal variance and zero mean **(in this case suppose $u,v\sim N(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $x=u+iv$, where $x_i\sim N(0,1)_\mathbb{C}$)**, i.e. , by a change of variable to polar coordinate in the pdf of the complex gaussian distribution.

Comment: Of course $L$ has a distribution, so I presume you are asking for some kind of formula.  It looks like a sum of Gumbel distributions to me, which means a formula will be [quite complicated,](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00477-006-0063-4) but apparently there exist [good approximations](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~mdecarv/papers/marques2015.pdf).  What kind of an answer are you looking for, then?

Comment: If there is a close pdf for $L$, but if not, an approximation looks good to me. I will be looking into your references and try to find something. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $Y_i \equiv - 2 \ln R_i$ and noting that $R_i \sim \text{Rayleigh}(1)$ you have the CDF:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y_i \leqslant y) 
&= \mathbb{P}(-Y_i/2 \geqslant -y/2) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(e^{-Y_i/2} \geqslant e^{-y/2}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(R_i \geqslant e^{- y/2}) \\[6pt]
&= \exp \Big( -\frac{e^{- y}}{2} \Big). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

You therefore obtain the density function:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) = \frac{d F_Y}{dy} (y) 
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \exp \Big( -y -\frac{e^{- y}}{2} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \text{Gumbel}(y| \mu = \ln 2, \beta = 1). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The mean and variance of this distribution are $\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \ln 2 + \gamma$ and $\mathbb{V}(Y_i) = \pi^2/6$, where $\gamma$ denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).  Your random variable $L_n$ can be written as an affine function of the sample mean of the random variables $Y_1,...,Y_n$ as follows:

$$L_n = n \Big( \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \bar{Y}_n \Big).$$

It follows that this random variable has mean:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(L_n) 
&= n \Big( \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbb{E}(\bar{Y}_n) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= n \Big( \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\ln 2 + \gamma) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\ln 2 - \gamma}{2} \cdot n, \\[6pt]
&\approx 0.05796576 \cdot n \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

and variance:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V}(L_n) 
&= \frac{n^2}{4} \cdot \mathbb{V}(\bar{Y}_n) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n^2}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6n} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\pi^2}{24} \cdot n \\[6pt]
&\approx 0.4112335 \cdot n. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) points out in the comments, the exact distribution of $L$ is a convolution of Gumbel distributions (see e.g., [Nadarajah 2006](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00477-006-0063-4)).  This exact distribution is complicated, but we can apply the [classical central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) to obtain an approximation using the normal distribution.  For large values of $n$ we have:

$$L_n \overset{\text{Approx}}{\sim} 
\text{N} \Big( \text{Mean} =  \frac{\ln 2 - \gamma}{2} \cdot n, \text{Var} = \frac{\pi^2}{24} \cdot n \Big).$$

Comment: This is a very pretty answer, thanks!